# Firebase Crashlytics not provide crash information in detail

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, firebase, crashlytics

Firebase crashlytics is not providing crash information in detail like in which file and on which line crash happen for some crashes.  So is there any way to know in which file and on which line exactly crash is produced.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How to trace this array out of bounds exception error

Comment: You should post some code so we can help you investigate what's the issue here.

Comment: @Lodoss Question is Why Fabric display  __hidden#1213_ line 351 this error only instead of error line no and file in which error contains ?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use array. Before getting object at index, check array.count > index. It will solve your future crashes as well.